# How to add/remove a class to the parent element of a checkbox on change in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a list with checkbox items in it, On selecting the checkbox I want to add a class to the parent li. How can I achieve this.

I am new to Angular.

```
<ul>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="1">Apple</li>
 <li class="active"><input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="2" checked>Orange</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="3">Pear</li>

</ul>
```

On selecting the checkbox I want to add the class active to the parent li

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `ng-class`:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-class="{active: orange}"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="orange" name="fruits[]" value="2" checked>Orange</li>
</ul>
```

The `{active: orange}` is saying, "only add the `active` class if `orange` is truthy."

`ng-model` two-way binds the value of the checkbox.  This gives you a variable `orange` to use inside the angular context.